# Access to multilevel relationships in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

can someone help me on getting data from multi level relationships in laravel?

I want to do something like
BagageAnnouncement->Announcement->user->profile->"name of the field"

```
 $data = $request->text;


     $filter = BagageAnnouncement::whereHas('announcement',function ($query) {
    })->whereHas('user', function ($query) {
    })->whereHas('profile',function($query){
        $query->where('level',$data)
})->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you guys for you answers I finally figure out a solution

```
  $data = $request->text;
    $filter = BagageAnnouncement::whereHas(
        'announcement.user.profile',
        function ($q2) use ($data) {
            $q2->where('level',$data);
        }
    )->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want as the result, but if you want a single result, you can do like this:

```
$bagage = BagageAnnouncement::where(specify_your_condition)->first();
$filter = $bagage->user->profile->name_of_the_field;
```

If you want an array of results, change the `first()` to `get()` and make use of `foreach`

Of course, you will need to set up the relationships in your models first.